# MYSQL: Update Database row Using SELECT and multiple JOINS

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

Essentially, I'm trying to repair a broken WooCommerce database for a client.

I have a table wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta and all of the _product_id values are erased. I am able to get the correct ID using this select statement. It will return all of the IDs, one per row as wanted.

```
SELECT
  wp_wc_order_product_lookup.product_id
FROM
  wp_woocommerce_order_items
INNER JOIN
  wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
    ON 
      wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id = wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id
INNER JOIN
  wp_wc_order_product_lookup
    ON
      wp_wc_order_product_lookup.order_id = wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_id
WHERE
  wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = '_product_id'
```

Now when I tried to write an update statement I can't get it to work. I've tried it several different ways. I read somewhere that `SET` has to be moved past the `INNER JOIN` lines.

```
UPDATE
  wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
INNER JOIN 
  wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta
    ON 
      wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id = wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id
INNER JOIN
  wp_wc_order_product_lookup
    ON
      wp_wc_order_product_lookup.order_id = wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_id
SET
  wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value = wp_wc_order_product_lookup.order_id
WHERE
  wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = '_product_id'
```

That code produces the following error `[Err] 1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta'`

`wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta`

[image: <code>wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta</code>]

`wp_wc_order_product_lookup`

[image: <code>wp_wc_order_product_lookup</code>]

Comment: Yep, time to get to grip with table/column aliases

Comment: Although in this instance it's just an obvious proofing error

Comment: @Strawberry Can you elaborate more? I'm not sure what you are trying to infer.

Comment: Grab a coffee and re-read your query. The inference will become self-evident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're after something like this:

```
 UPDATE wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta x
  JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items y
    ON y.order_item_id = x.order_item_id
  JOIN wp_wc_order_product_lookup z
    ON z.order_id = y.order_id
   SET x.meta_value = z.order_id
 WHERE x.meta_key = '_product_id'
```

Comment: That worked! I'll look more into it later. I've wasted so much time trying different things. I did have to change the set value to product_id. I'm assuming you purposely chose order_id because i had it highlighted in the screenshot, but that was an unintentional highlight.

On second look, I do see that I had it wrong in my query anyways.
Thanks for the help regardless.

Answer (score -1):

you can solve this issue with simple PHP script, here is logic
1) select unique product_id and order_id from wp_wc_order_product_lookup
2) Result set from step 1 is used to update the table wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta with the help of looping

Let me know if face any issue to write script in PHP then I will provide to code.

Comment: I knew I could do it via PHP but I was trying to do it via SQL. I knew it had to be possible with SQL, but I was just tired and making mistakes as @Strawberry showed.